# Is it possible to deduct the template type of a templated parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have a template class, with an internal method that is itself templated.

Consider the following minimal working example

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
class P{
public:
    template <typename U>
    P<U> call(std::function< P<U> (T)> f){
        return f(return_value);
    }
    T return_value;
};

P<int> foo() {
    P<int> value = P<int>();
    return value;
}

P<float> bar(int arg) {
    return P<float>();
}

int main()
{
    auto res = foo().call<float>(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in the main function, the compiler forces me to to specify the `float` type for calling the `call()` function, eventhough the type should be obvious from passing over the `bar()` function, that specifies the `float` type.

Is it somehow possible to deduct the type so that the code in the main function can be simplified to the following statement:

```
auto res = foo().call(bar);
```

Comment: `auto call(U&& f)`? Is there a reason you are using `std::function`?

Comment: @user17732522: No specific reason, i just need to capture a function

Comment: Then you don't need it. `std::function` is only required if you need to store callables of different types as the same type. Just rewrite the declaration to use a forwarding reference `auto call(U&& f)` or just any type by value `auto call(U f)` and it'll work as you want it to.

Comment: It's a chicken and egg problem. The `U` type can (I suppose: non tryied) be deduced from a `std::function` argument. But `bar` isn't a `std::function` argument; just an argument that can be converted to a `std::function<P<U>(T)>`, given that `U` and `T` are known. So or you call `call()` with `call(std::function{bar});`, so the compiler construct a `std::function<P<float>(int)`, and then `U` is deduced as `float`, or you explicit that `U` is `float` and calling `call<float>(bar)`, `bar` is converted to `std::function<P<float>(int)>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function` is not the type that you should use whenever you want to pass a function around. `std::function` is a type that uses type erasure to be able to store different types of callables in one type. If you don't need that then you need no `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
class P{
public:
    template <typename F>
    auto call(F f){
        return f(return_value);
    }
    T return_value{};  // don't forget to initialize !
};

P<int> foo() {
    P<int> value = P<int>();
    return value;
}

P<float> bar(int arg) {
    return P<float>();
}

int main()
{
    auto res = foo().call(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Using partial specializatzion you can get the return type of `bar` and you can get the `float` from `P<float>`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class P;

// get return type from function
template <typename T> struct return_type;

template <typename R,typename...args>
struct return_type<R(args...)> { using type = R; };

// get T from P<T>
template <typename P> struct P_arg;   
template <typename T> struct P_arg< P<T> > { using type = T; };

// combine both
template <typename F>
struct get {
    using type = typename P_arg<typename return_type<F>::type >::type;
};

template<typename T>
class P{
public:
    template <typename F>
    auto call(F f){
        return f(return_value);
    }
    T return_value{};
};

P<float> bar(int arg) {
    return P<float>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v< get<decltype(bar)>::type,float>;
    return 0;
}
```

Though that does not really help here, because you cannot use it to decalre the return type of `P::call`, as it requires `P<float>` to be already complete.